# How do I find & delete multiple rows in excel 365 based on the cell text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I have a spreadsheet of company addresses.  Each company is listed in a row and has a code assigned(text) in column A.  I want to efficiently find multiple rows based on their company code(the text in cells in col A) and delete those rows.  How can I do this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Use Remove duplicates on the Data tab.

Comment: Thanks, used this

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on the filter for these columns, filter for those you are wanting to delete, delete them and then remove the blank rows

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for response, helped for something else I'm doing with fewer rows